# JAVA - Converting android application into fragment styled application

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My app has `main.xml` and `MainActivity`. I wanted to convert it to a tabbed styled app. By the help of this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/), I've successfully made a UI with a tabbed style.

Now I have to put the codes in my `MainActivty`(not tabbed style) to the fragments. i don't know how to do it. when i just put the codes to my `ToolsFragment.java`, it doesn't work.

Here are my codes:

```
//To get ip address using netcfg
private String ipnc()
{
    int e = doNETCFG().indexOf("10.");
    if (e == -1)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        String ipnc1 = doNETCFG().substring(e, e + 15);
        String ipnc2[] = ipnc1.split("/");
        String ipnc3 = ipnc2[0];
        return ipnc3;
    }
}

//To generate netcfg from command line
public String doNETCFG()
{
    String str = null;
    try
    {
        Process localProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/netcfg");
        BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localProcess.getInputStream()));
        char[] arrayOfChar = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer localStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (true)
        {
            int i = localBufferedReader.read(arrayOfChar);
            if (i <= 0)
            {
                localBufferedReader.close();
                localProcess.waitFor();
                str = localStringBuffer.toString();
                break;
            }
            localStringBuffer.append(arrayOfChar, 0, i);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException localIOException)
    {
        Log.e("TAG", localIOException.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
    catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException)
    {
        Log.e("TAG", localInterruptedException.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
    return str;
}

//To enable/disable mobile data
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled)
{
    final ConnectivityManager conman;
    conman =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService 
    (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass;
    try
    {
        conmanClass =
            Class.forName(conman.getClass
                          ().getName());
        final Field
            iConnectivityManagerField =
            conmanClass.getDeclaredField
        ("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.
            setAccessible(true);
        final Object
            iConnectivityManager =
            iConnectivityManagerField.get
        (conman);
        final Class
            iConnectivityManagerClass =
            Class.forName
        (iConnectivityManager.getClass
         ().getName());
        final Method
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod =
            iConnectivityManagerClass.
            getDeclaredMethod
        ("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.
            setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
    }
    catch
    (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch
    (InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch
    (NoSuchMethodException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch
    (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch
    (NoSuchFieldException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//To play success alert tone
public void playAlertTone()
{
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (i >= 1)
                    return;
                MediaPlayer localMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), 0x7f040000);
                localMediaPlayer.start();
                i++;
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100 + localMediaPlayer.getDuration());
                    localMediaPlayer.release();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
        .start();
}
```

What should I do? Do I have to put this into another activity and call it in fragment? If that's the case, how?
Or convert it to a code executable in fragments and run it there? How can I do this?

I'm a newbie in android programming. Thanks!

Comment: "i've successfully created a tabbed style interface using fragment but i can't figure out how to convert my code to a code executable in fragments."-- what does this mean?

Comment: my app has main.xml and MainActivity. i wanted to convert it to a tabbed styled app by the help of this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/. now i have to put the codes in my MainActivty(not tabbed style) to the fragments. i don't know how to do it. when i just put the codes to my ToolsFragment.java, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

when you convert an application to fragment based structure, you have to consider one thing that the context is same for all the fragments in an activity. You will get it by calling `getActivity()`. So save your context first and use it where ever you want the context.

From your question you are developing an application with tabs. So you may have to create fragments as many as the tabs. You can put your code for each tab in the corresponding fragment.

Now to communicate between the fragments the best way is to use callbacks in your parent activity.

A simple tutorial for implementing fragments can be found [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm)

The communication between fragments is explained [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is it possible to run the doNETCFG() on my code in a fragment? I've put this code on my ToolsFragment.java and set this String to one of my textviews.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments do most of the things activities do. The reason why they were introduced (one of the reasons at least) was so you can place the code in them instead of in the activities of your app. If you think this way, you will notice that you will only need a small number of activities.

I am not sure what you mean by "convert it to a code executable in fragments". You can place your code inside your fragments (use methods) and then simply call those methods.

If you are not sure how Fragments work, I would highly recommend reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

I hope this gives you an idea of how to get your code to work in fragments.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question. I've read a lot of tutorials, articles about fragments. I can't get this working.